# Unable to edit resources or create .aps file in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: resources, editor, visual-studio-2005, corrupt

I recently migrated a large-scale VS2005 solution to a new development machine running the same version of VS2005, and everything is linking and compiling without any problems. However, when I attempt to edit any of the project resources (e.g. 'projectname.rc') using the resource editor, I receive the following error message:

**"Visual C++ Win32 Resource Editors
The Resource File is corrupted, or the editor for this type of file is not available. Create another resource file or install an editor, then try again."**

I've attempted to rectify the problem a number of ways, and noted the following details:

- I can confirm that a blank, newly created resource file can be created and edited successfully in the environment.
- The entire solution has been cleaned, intermediate files deleted, and rebuilt.
- Intermediate resource scripts (projectname.rc and projectname.res) can be opened in an external resource editor (e.g. ResEdit), and I can confirm that these scripts have been correctly generated
- The binary resource file (projectname.aps) is NOT successfully generated. A 0-byte file is created when attempting to launch the resource editor, but is immediately deleted upon receiving the "Resource file corrupted..." error listed above. I suspect that this is the crux of the problem
- As noted in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/e4ef7904-0947-4792-aa4a-b28077146d02) (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/e4ef7904-0947-4792-aa4a-b28077146d02), all include paths have been modified to ensure that none include trailing backslash characters

I'm eager to hear if anyone has any suggested solutions or further steps; in a nutshell, it seems that the IDE is failing to create a binary resource file for use with the Resource Editor, despite the solution compiling and executing without errors

IDE details:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Version 8.0.50727.42  (RTM.050727-4200)
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727
Installed Edition: Standard
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005   77633-235-0000007-41284

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having the same problem, I've solved this. For me, the issue was with rcxdti.dll, the .RC extension compiler, found in \VC\vcpackages.

By replacing the original rcxdti.dll with a more recent version of the file from my installation of Visual Studio 2010, all .RC resource files are now fully editable and open without any problems in the resource editor.

Regarding the root cause, I doubt that the DLL was currupt, since it was a brand new VS2005 installation. I suspect that it was more likely to be a subversion incompatibility between the rcxdti.dll files of two  Visual Studio 2005 development machiens. Of course, if anyone has a better idea of the root cause, I'm very eager to hear it.